# ASM x86 Function call : best method to save EBP and common registers (EAX, EBX, ...)

Tags: assembly, x86

I'd like to know what is the best method to save common registers (EAX, EBX and so on) in addition with EBP.
Here is my sample code. It juste make a call to my write function, passing the string adress and lenght in parameter (parameters are put in the stack).
In the write function, I save EBP, give it his new value, get back the parameters and call the write syscall.

```
.section .data

    ask_number_str:
        .ascii "Hello world"
    anstr_end:
        .set ANSTR_SIZE, anstr_end - ask_number_str


.section .bss

.section .text

    .globl main

    main:
        movl $42, %eax
        movl $123, %ebx
        movl $456, %ecx
        movl $789, %edx
        pushl $ANSTR_SIZE
        pushl $ask_number_str
        call write
        add $8, %esp

    exit:
        movl $1, %eax
        movl $0, %ebx
        int $0x80

    write:
        pushl %ebp
        movl %esp, %ebp        
        movl $4, %eax
        movl $1, %ebx
        movl 8(%ebp), %ecx
        movl 12(%ebp), %edx
        int $0x80
        popl %ebp
        ret
```

I'd like to add the save of EAX, EBX, ECX and EDX on function call. I see three ways to save the common registers:

- First, save them in the write function, before the "mov %esp, %ebp" (before assigning the new adress for ebp).
  => Problem : ESP, and so EBP will point in the stack after the common register values, so I will have to go deeper in the stack to find the parameters (I will have to pass through the values of EAX, EBX, ECX, EDX before finding the parameters)
- Second, save them in the write function, after the "mov %esp, %ebp".
  => Problem : ESP, and so EBP will point in the stack before the common register values, so I will have to go furtherer in the stack to play with local variables (I will have to pass the 4 values, if I save EAX, EBX, ECX and EDX, to have the beginning adress of my local variables).
- Third, save them in the calling function (here the main), before the function call (and before the push of parameters). No problem of stack, but this is not very elegant I think, and I need to add 8 lines for each call (4 push before the call and 4 pop after).

So, what is for you the best method? Surely another method I didn't think of :)

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have decided to use a frame pointer, the usual thing to do is save them after setting up `ebp`. Your saved registers are not different from any local variables, you can even access them with `mov` instructions instead of `push`/`pop` if you like and you may put them under your other variables if you don't want to use bigger offsets.

Note that frame pointers are usually not required as you can address relative to `esp`. Also, common calling conventions typically allow `eax`, `ecx` and `edx` to be modified, so if you adhere to such all you need to save is `ebx`.

Comment: Not using ebp can make the program hard for debug. And using esp as a pointer to the local variables and arguments can introduce hard to detect bugs when the stack is used by the function, because the esp register is changed.

Comment: Omitting `ebp` doesn't affect debugging much, if at all. Using `esp` only is common practice in performance critical code (which may very well be why you are using asm), even compilers do this. Normally `esp` is not changed in the function body so it's just as stable as `ebp`. I doubt it's any significant source of hard to detect bugs, when writing asm you have plenty of others :) x86 doesn't have very many registers, using `ebp` as another GPR will probably be more beneficial than as a frame pointer.

Answer (score -1):

if you are unsure about the registers' situation, these instructions below could save the day easily.

[PUSHA/PUSHAD -- Push all General Registers](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2005/readings/i386/PUSHA.htm)
[POPA/POPAD -- Pop all General Registers](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2004/readings/i386/POPA.htm)

These instructions push and pop the general purpose and SI/ESI , DI/EDI registers  in certain order.

The order for PUSHA/PUSHAD instruction is as follows.

```
Opcode  Instruction  Clocks   Description

60      PUSHA        18       Push AX, CX, DX, BX, original SP, BP, SI, and DI
60      PUSHAD       18       Push EAX, ECX, EDX, EBX, original ESP, EBP ESI, and EDI
```

And the order for POPA/POPAD instruction is as follows. (in reverse order)

```
Opcode   Instruction   Clocks   Description

61       POPA          24       Pop DI, SI, BP, SP, BX, DX, CX, and AX
61       POPAD         24       Pop EDI, ESI, EBP, ESP(***),EBX, EDX, ECX, and EAX
```

*** The ESP value is discarded instead of loaded into ESP.

Comment: Unfortunately, AMD removed PUSHA from x86_64.  Probably because there are so many unused registers with every call.

Comment: It's true that PUSHA exists, but it's a terrible answer to the question of "best way to save/restore registers in a function".  It's very slow, and since it overwrites ALL the GP registers except ESP, you would have to store your desired return value into the restore slot for EAX before running it.